# How to find top n overlapping items in two lists of tuples (Python)

Tags: python

Given

```
a = [('AB', 11), ('CD', 12), ('EF', 13), ('GG', 1332)]
```

and

```
b = [('AB', 411), ('XX', 132), ('EF', 113), ('AF', 113), ('FF', 113)]
```

If `n = 3`, I want to only consider the top 3 elements in each lists and return tuples that have same first element (the string).

For example, I want to return `['AB','EF']` in this case.

How can I do this?

Comment: By top n elements, do you mean the first elements? You can use list slicing to get first n elements: `a[:n]`, `b[:n]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Counter` for this like:

#### Code:

```
a = [('AB', 11), ('CD', 12), ('EF', 13), ('GG', 1332)]
b = [('AB', 411), ('XX', 132), ('EF', 113), ('AF', 113), ('FF', 113)]

from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(x[0] for x in a[:3] + b[:3])
print([x for x, c in counts.items() if c == 2])
```

And without any imports, use a set:

```
print(set((x[0] for x in a[:3])).intersection(set((x[0] for x in b[:3]))))
```

#### Results:

```
['AB', 'EF']
{'AB', 'EF'}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using a library?

Comment: Counter is a builtin.  You mean without any imports at all?

Comment: `if c == 2` might not always be correct if `a` and `b` contains duplicate items.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
def overlapping(n, tups_a, tups_b):
    overlapping = set(map(lambda x: x[0], tups_a[:n])).intersection(set(map(lambda x: x[0], tups_b[:n])))
    return list(overlapping)

overlap = overlapping(3, a, b)

['AB', 'EF']
```

Answer (score 0):

using set intersection (better complexity over list's `in`):

```
def overlapping(x,y, topn=3):
    return {i[0] for i in x[:topn]} & {i[0] for i in y[:topn]}

overlapping(a,b)
```

outputs:

```
{'AB', 'EF'}
```

### Exaplanation:

```
{i[0] for i in x[:topn]}
```

set comprehensions, equivalent to `set(i[0] for i in x[:topn])`

```
{...} & {...}
```

set intersection, equivalent to `set(..).intersection(set(...))`

Answer (score -1):

Well first, we can start off with a `for` loop. We want to loop from 0 to `n`, check the tuples of `a` and `b` at those indices, and then check if that tuple's first element match.

```
matches = [a [index] [0] for index in range (n) if a [index] [0] == b [index] [0]]
```

Which does the same thing as:

```
matches = []
for index in range (n):
    if a [index] [0] == b [index] [0]: matches.append a [index] [0]
```

Comment: ...And if you have a valid reason for downvoting, that's fine, just explain it with a comment!